# How to set up the exception handlers for Cortex-M3

Tags: exception, cortex-m, thumb

I am beginning to do some simple projects on a STM32L152 Cortex-M3...

I read that the M3 is thumb2 only and thus, we need to keep the LSB of the exception handlers addresses to a '1' in order to stay in thumb mode.

```
.thumb
.section .startup, "ax"
exc_vectors:
       .word top_of_stack
       .word reset_handler
       .word NMI_handler
       .word hardfault_handler
           .
           .
reset_handler:
           @some code here
```

Since the instructions are 16-bit or 32-bit, is it correct to say that the 'reset_handler' symbol will have an address with LSB = 0?

If so, generally, how/when/where does one set the LSB of the handlers symbols (reset_handler, NMI_handler, etc) to '1'?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The C compiler will do this by itself, so you may relax.

The Cortex-M3 core is 32-bit. The 'reset_handler' vector has address 0x04. You are right, all vectors will have LSB == 0, BUT!
If your reset vector starts at address 0x0B0C, like this:

```
              ResetISR:
00000b0c:   F7FFBEC4 B.W             _c_int00
00000b10:   4770     BX
```

then the compiler will write it inside the vector table as 0x0B0D, like this:

```
00000004:   00000B0D ANDEQ
```

Comment: thanks, 2 more questions:how will the C compiler know that 'ResetISR' is a exception handler routine (in order to add 1 to the address)? Also, what if i am using assembly to write my startup and ISR routines, instead of using C? Do i simply add 1 to the handlers addresses in the vector table?

Comment: when you create a C project then the startup code will be generated; it will include the vector table with #pragma directive to place it with the vector table rules, and in this vector there woul be the pointer to ResetISR function. If you use assembler then you just add 1, that's right.